# Downsides of a bullet point for 3D archery

Tags: archery, arrows, 3d-archery

I would like to have bullet points for 3D archery. I just think that they look better than combo/field tips. However, I was suggested that I shouldn't use them for 3D archery.

What are the disadvantages of bullet points compared to combo/field points in 3D archery?

Comment: I could only think the suggestion came from the idea you would shoot the 3Ds as you were practincing huting and therefore you would only need to unscrew your point and screw in your broadhead. I think if you are doing field shooting as an actaul competitor, you are looking for performance and high scores. To achieve that a single piece point would be better than an insert and a point and the weight could vary as much as a few (1-2) grams.

Answer (score 4):

They didnt give you any reason for that suggestion?

Sometimes depends on clubs, one club I was member of years ago was extremely fussy about which were allowed and which not.
There is a difference in aerodynamics but at the end it comes down to the target: the intent is to reduce damage to it. The field/combo that flare out to the wider shoulder limit penetration in an harder material so to make it easier to pull out the arrow, in some places the targets are foam and the club might want bullet points.